# How does AngularJS know to check/trigger the 'isToggled' condition in this working example?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning some basics in angularjs and I've somewhat accidentally stumbled across a pattern that works, but I'm not sure why. Also not sure if I'm doing it in an 'angular best practices' kind of way. This example is greatly simplified from what I'm really working on, but the general concept is the same: *setting visibility of children based on a toggle on the parent*

It seems to my angular-naive self, that it must somehow be watching functions which use the  `toggledGroups` array and then ???. The conditional `ng-show` *does* work, I just don't really get why the `ng-show="isToggled(group)"` gets re-evaluated since the array I'm modifying isn't on `$scope`.

- Do all functions that exist on `$scope` get re-evaluated on every `$digest`? If so, this seems to me like it could create a bottleneck on `ng-repeats` over large data sets.
- As I alluded to above, is this an acceptable pattern or is there a better/'more angular' way I should think about this interaction?

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.service('TransportationService', function(){
    var groups = [{
        group: "planes",
        items: ["Airbus A300", "Extra 300S", "Stearman"]
    },  {
        group: "trains",
        items: ["Flying Scotsman", "The Rocket", "Silver Streak"]
    }, {
        group: "automobiles",
        items: ["Veyron", "Vanquish", "FF", "Continental GT"]
    }];

    return {
        groups: groups
    }
});

app.controller('TransportationController', ['$scope', 'TransportationService', function($scope, ts){
    var toggledGroups = [];

    function isToggled(group) {
        return toggledGroups.indexOf(group) > -1;
    }

    function toggleGroup(group) {
        var index = toggledGroups.indexOf(group);
        if (index > -1) {
          toggledGroups.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
          toggledGroups.push(group);
        }
    }

    $scope.groups = ts.groups;
    $scope.isToggled = isToggled;
    $scope.toggleGroup = toggleGroup;
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="TransportationController">
    <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <h3>{{group.group}}</h3>
        <button ng-click="toggleGroup(group)">Toggle</button>
        <ul ng-show="isToggled(group)">
            <li ng-repeat="item in group.items">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wpHZg/1/

Comment: Which conditional statement are you referring to that gets re-evaulated?

Comment: the `isToggled(group)`. Sorry, I worded that poorly

Comment: I put some console.log's within isToggled function, noticed it calls it 6 times strangely each time...

Comment: You are right. All the properties on $scope are watched and evaluated. isToggled(group) will be re-evaluated on button-click as it tries to re-render the view. There are a couple of things that you can do to make it a bit better, although unrelated to your question. See the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/jain208/wpHZg/6/. First, I have replaced ng-show with ng-if, which is a bit more performant than ng-show, plus the element doesn't occupy space in DOM. Secondly, I have simplified your toggleGroup method by adding an IsVisible property on group.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: I noticed that, too. In both my demo and my real app, the `isToggled` function gets called twice for each render (34 items, 68 calls per render). Happens with both `ng-if` and `ng-show`

Comment: @BLSully You need to toggle it the way he is showing below, then it will only get called **once** per click. Magic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. Every time a digest cycle kicks off, it executes that function. You are also correct in the fact that it's more expensive. How much more expensive? Depends on the size of your data set. From the logic you show, I can't imagine it would be too hard on the CPU, but you should consider the fact that it's going to pile up on all of your other application logic. From the way I see it, you could take 2 courses of action to reduce the load on the client CPU.

1) easy: add a toggled property to your groups:

```
$scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
  group.toggled = !group.toggled
};

<ul ng-if="group.toggled"></ul>
```

2) More complex: Allows for some DRYness, make a directive! :D

```
app.directive('toggler', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, elem) {
       elem.find('.button-toggler').on('click', function() {
         elem.find('.togglee').toggle();
       });
     }
   };
});

<div toggler="">
  <button class="button-toggler">Toggle Me Hard!</button>
  <ul class="togglee" style="display:none"></ul>
</div>
```

The second one allows for you to transport your directive to other parts of your code with ease. It also will not kick off a digest cycle as it is all jQuery based (which in this case is good because you're not changing any scope data on click). Either way, you're going to have a cleaner application.

Comment: Also remember to use `track by` in your `ng-repeat`s. It reduces the amount of rerendering that the application does on the DOM.

Comment: Also, use ng-if instead of ng-show whenever possible.

Comment: True that, @AbhishekJain

Comment: `track by` and `ng-if` can make huge improvements agreed!

Comment: @Mike: I'll have to look up `track by` and `ng-if`. I was not aware of those. Thanks!

Comment: I've now read your answer a few times and I think the advantages of the 2nd option finally sunk in. The first option was the immediate alternative to my solution that came to mind, but it feels bad keeping UI state on the "data". Maybe it's not, but I could see myself getting into trouble with that. I'll experiment with that train of thought.

Comment: It all really depends on what the requirements are. Keeping UI state in the data isn't so bad if you're setting a few flags. I would reconsider if you're attaching whole objects related to UI. The main problem I've encountered with such a thing is that when you have to resubmit data to the server, it might be invalid (depending on how the server interprets the extra data), so you would have to groom on submission.

Comment: Backend is .NET which is (surprisingly) forgiving of spurious/missing properties if you're serializing an object back to an `asmx webservice` which is what we're still using for better/worse. In this case, the data being passed back to the server will have to be groomed for other reasons anyway so that does make it not a terribly big deal. My hang-ups are more about teaching myself the 'right way' vs 'shortcuts' merely so I don't fall into a pattern of poor practice as I become familiar with angular.